# Arduino sketch with Serial.available() passes twice

Tags: arduino, serial-port

When I test `Serial.available()` or `Serial.available() > 0` in my `loop()` function, it appears to return `true` *twice* each time I enter serial data. The second time, it sets the `throttle` value in my code to `0`. Here is the code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo rc_rotor;

int throttle = 0; // servo position indicates throttle position.

String s_throttle_set = "Throttle set to: ";
String s_throttle_read = "Reading throttle value: ";
String s_action_error = "No action known for input value: ";

void setup() 
{
  rc_rotor.attach(9);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(! Serial);
  Serial.println("Throttle value: 0 through 255, or 999 to read current value.");
}

void loop() 
{
  rc_rotor.write(throttle);
  delay(20);
  if (Serial.available()) 
  { 
    int temp_throttle = Serial.parseInt();

    if (temp_throttle >= 0 && temp_throttle <= 180)
    {
      throttle = temp_throttle;
      Serial.println(s_throttle_set + throttle);
    } 
    else if (temp_throttle == 999) 
    {
      Serial.println(s_throttle_read + throttle);
    } 
    else 
    {
      Serial.println(s_action_error + temp_throttle);
    }
  }
}
```

Please note this code is not my final masterpiece. Much of it is from publicly available examples. Anyway, the statement `if (Serial.available())` succeeds twice. By that I mean, it is `true` when I type in a value such as `125`, and a moment later it will be 'true' again when I have typed in nothing additional. I only expect one value to go through this way. The result is that my `throttle` is being set to the value I enter, and then almost immediately re-set to `0`. Why would something like this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out there is no mysterious problem with the hardware or the code, as I first suspected there was. Actually, the solution is simply to select "no line ending" in the Arduino Serial Monitor's dropdown option (by default, I guess mine was set to "New Line"). Without the additional character being inserted by the Serial Monitor, everything behaves as expected.

One thing I did not expect is how the Arduino software interprets the newline. I debugged by printing the ascii values that were making it through my if-statement. First of all, the Serial Monitor sent the number I typed in, followed moments later by ascii 10, which is the line feed character. Fine, no problem. But then `Serial.parseInt()` chewed on that line feed for a moment (there was a slight but noticeable delay), then fed the numeral `0` to my function. It took me a little while to figure out why. Here is an explanation from the Serial part of the Arduino Language Reference:

> parseInt()
>
> Description
>
> Looks for the next valid integer in the incoming serial stream.
> parseInt() inherits from the Stream utility class.
>
> In particular:
>
> - Initial characters that are not digits or a minus sign, are skipped;
> - Parsing stops when no characters have been read for a configurable
>   time-out value, or a non-digit is read;
> - ***If no valid digits were read
>   when the time-out (see Serial.setTimeout()) occurs, 0 is returned;***

So `Serial.available()` is `true` after the line feed character enters the buffer, but there is no "valid digit" according to `Serial.parseInt()`. Understandably... we are looking at an empty buffer that finally times out. Therefore `Serial.parseInt()` returns `0` and the code that follows proceeds with that value.

The code in the question assumed that the only input would be integers coming over the serial connection, which is actually a pretty fragile assumption. If you need to use `Serial.parseInt` in a situation where empty buffers (null), line feeds or other unexpected characters might come through, it should just be a matter of filtering the input better than I did in the example code.

Comment: This begs the question, how would you handle the newline if it HAD to receive a newline for whatever reason?

Comment: @BalázsBörcsök If you don't control the input source to make it send cleaner data, then 'it depends' on how complicated the stream is. In a simple case like this, `Serial.peek()` should return -1 if you have an empty buffer. Something like `if (Serial.peek() == -1) {return;}` gets you out without feeding the unexpected null to `parseInt()`. If more complicated, I might compare `peek()` to an expected list/range of values, and either return, or send the data to error handling code if it doesn't match expected values. Or even pre-filter/massage data through a server before feeding to Arduino.